# Find and delete resource files using batch file

Tags: batch-file, find, kill-process, delete-file

I have never written a batch file so please bear with me.

I want to find resource file from current working directory of batch file. If it exist then I have stop aspnet_wp.exe process (if running) and delete this resource file. Later run resgen command to create a fresh resource file (new file name should be same as old one).

Comment: %~dp0 is used to find current working dir

Comment: to run resgen command, it should be like this. resgen path/a.txt

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) command.  You can include a call to this to stop the process.

For example if the resource file is named "resource.txt",

```
IF EXIST resource.txt (
    taskkill /im aspnet_wp.exe
    del resource.txt
    resgen
)
```

Comment: how about finding a file and deleting it. I did something like this.  set curdir=%~dp0 set path=%curdir%%\Document.txt%  IF EXIST curdir\Document.txt (DEL curdir\Document.txt)...please tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: echo on
set curdir=%~dp0
set path=%curdir%%\*.resouces%
echo %path%
IF EXIST path
taskkill /f /im aspnet_wp.exe
(DEL path)
pause

Comment: but resgen is the cmd used in visual studion cmd prompt..when i use in regular cmd it says cmd not found..

Comment: it is throwing Taskkill is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: That is odd because taskkill.exe should be in c:\windows\system32.

Comment: yes its in path u have specified but i dont know why it isnt working

Comment: hey YME can u pls help me out with using resgen cmd..this cmd is related to .net